# iOS Security Question - What are the targets support files and what do they do?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, xcode12

I've been developing iOS apps for about 18 months now, and I am mostly self-taught. I was recently hired and brought onto a very large project with a lot of moving pieces. I'd like to provide a broad outline for the owner of the application who hired me and I also want to do a security check before presenting the outline to him and others, as well as suggest to him that we should ultimately hire an iOS security expert.

Moreover, after a brief overview of the project, I’ve found a few things that stick out to me and I was wondering if they also stick out to anyone viewing this post:

Below the main project file, there is a Xcode project file, named: 'Pods'

**Project - Pods**

- > **Podfile:**
  > (Lists all pods); will do a separate post for specifics on this).
- > **Frameworks:**
  > (Contains all frameworks from cocoa pods we use).
- > **Pods:**
  > (Contains many folders, each named after each cocoa pods pod we use).
- > **Products:**
  > (List all of the cocoa pods we use, followed by a .framework after each).
  > ***Ex:** 'Alamofire.framework'*
- > **Targets Support Files:**
  > Contains two folders:

  - **1.** Pods-UberApp-Uber
  - **2.** Pods-UberApp-UberDev

In each of the two folders within ***'Targets Support Files'*** the following files exist (image link below), with the beginning (for the first set of items within the first file) being *'Pods-UberApp-Uber'* or (for the second set of items within the second file)   *'Pods-UberApp-UberDev'*:

[Screenshot of *'Pods-UberApp-Uber'* / *'Pods-UberApp-UberDev'* file items, previously  described](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ar8zo.png)

What are these files and are they present for every Xcode project/iOS app?

**Note:** Uber is just the demo name of the app for sake of privacy and understanding. Thx.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These files are autogenerated by [cocoapods](https://cocoapods.org/)

The only file that you may edit in `Pods` project, is `Podfile`. It contains all your dependencies, and may contain some custom settings for configuring them.

If you open `Podfile` location in the file system, you'll find `Podfile.lock` nearby: it contains all versions for installed dependencies since the last `pod install` or `pod update`. You can try removing `Pods` folder and run `pod install` from terminal inside folder with `Podfile`, it should recreate the `Pods` directory.

So all these files on your screenshot are just needed by Xcode to build dependencies for you.